# ActionListener and ActionEvent in separate classes

Tags: java

I am making a Tic-tac-toe game and have my GUI set up in its own class, along with a separate class for the game logic and a separate main class. What I need to do is set up the button events so when the player clicks a button, the imageicon will change to an "X" or "O". How do I set up the ActionListener in my GUI class but be able to change the event in my game class?

Here is my code at the moment:

GUI class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class TicTacToeGui {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
public JButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9;

public void ticTacToeGui() {
    createForm();
    createButtons();

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

public void createForm() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    frame.setSize(618, 647);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);


}

public void createButtons() {
    btn1 = new JButton();
    btn1.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn1);

    btn2 = new JButton();
    btn2.setBounds(200, 0, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn2);

    btn3 = new JButton();
    btn3.setBounds(400, 0, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn3);

    btn4 = new JButton();
    btn4.setBounds(0, 200, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn4);

    btn5 = new JButton();
    btn5.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn5);

    btn6 = new JButton();
    btn6.setBounds(400, 200, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn6);

    btn7 = new JButton();
    btn7.setBounds(0, 400, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn7);

    btn8 = new JButton();
    btn8.setBounds(200, 400, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn8);

    btn9 = new JButton();
    btn9.setBounds(400, 400, 200, 200);
    panel.add (btn9);
}

}
```

Game class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class OnePlayer {

TicTacToeGui gui = new TicTacToeGui();

public void gameStart() {

    gui.btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Icon i = new ImageIcon("x.png");
            gui.btn1.setIcon(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by change event? Can you be more specific of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to be able to change the imageicon of the buttons that are in the GUI class, using code from the game class.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `gameStart()` after you declare gui.

```
public class OnePlayer 
{
   TicTacToeGui gui = new TicTacToeGui();
   gameStart();

   public void gameStart()
   {
      //your existing code
   }
}
```

although I wouldn't go this way. A much better way is dont declare your buttons as public fields. Pass in an array list of action listeners to gui class and call action Performed in your OnePlayer class which will actually iterate over the listeners and call actionPerformed on each of them.